# Shell script that passes parameter to gnuplot does not export the diagram (epslatex)

Tags: bash, automation, latex, gnuplot, figures

I have created a shell script (.run) that accepts the prefix for the names of the pictures as a parameter, and then calls gnuplot. However, for some reason, the picture is not saved. The code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
molecule=$1

echo "Plotting DFT-ADF PY results for $molecule"
echo "Tranmission plot (negatory SO)"
gnuplot -p << EOF
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal epslatex size 5,3 color colortext
set output '$molecule_trans.tex'

plot cos(x) w l title 'cos(x)', sin(x) w l title 'sin(x)'

EOF
```

For my bachelor thesis I have to make several plots that are the same. Additionally, the computational cluster uses a qeueing system. For the purpose of being true to this system, I have created several shell scripts that automatically do stuff. In particular, about 45 simulations are called by the shell scripts, followed by a shell script that enters each simulations' directory and uses python files to evaluate the data into [**.dat**] files. Next, it should use a gnuplot file to make the graph. I use EPSLaTeX to make my figures, because it is so much nicer. However, in the current implementation this required me to manually edit the various latex files to rename the pictures.

Comment: I have just determined that the files are created. Apparently, i made an error in the shell script, in such a way that the files are saved as ".eps" and ".tex", which are (naturally) hidden automatically.

I have edited it so that it uses $1 instead of $molecule, and it works.

I hope someone else finds the topic useful.

Comment: Concerning other solutions: Must everything be inside one file? You could e.g. have a configuration file for gnuplot, which is loaded automatically or which you can include with `load 'settings.gp'`. Then you can pass variables via the commandline like `gnuplot -e "var='$var'" general_script.gp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you'll need more variables and do not want a `$1`, `$2`... mess:

You must use brackets around the variable name

```
set output '${molecule}_trans.tex'
```

because the underscore is a valid character for variable names, and `bash` looks for the variable `$molecule_trans`, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

Comment: Hint for future readers: I always replace the gnuplot line with something like `cat > script << EOF` to diagnose the problem. You have the actual result-script like this.